# Recupera valores utilizando classes e pdo sem passar pela url

Tags: php, pdo, url

Boa tarde, tenho uma classe onde passo todos os métodos `insert`, `update`, `delete`, `consulta(fechall)` e `consulta(fech($id))`

Abaixo eu mostro a classe de `consulta(fech($id))`

```
public function selId($id){
    $sqlId = "SELECT * FROM web_cadcli WHERE idcad_cliente = ':id_us', nom_cliente = $this->getNome($nome), ema_cliente = $this->getEmail($email), senha_email = $this->senha($senha)  ";
    $sqlId = $this->con->conectar()->prepare($sqlId);
    $sqlId->bindParam(':id_us', $this->cod,   PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sqlId->bindParam(1,        $this->nome,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlId->bindParam(2,        $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlId->bindParam(3,        $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlId->execute();
    return ($sqlId->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }//retorna o Id do Usuario - testar
```

Quero buscar valores no banco de dados com ID e posteriormente recuperar no meu formulário

Abaixo mostro meu formulário com o código onde preciso recuperar o valores.

```
<?PHP
        $Objeto = new Usuario(); 
        $usuario = $Objeto->selId(); ?><!--SELECIONO O ID DO METODOS selId-->

          <input name="id_ui" type="hidden" value="id_usu"/>
          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
            <input type="nome" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="<?php $usuario->setNome($nome); ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="<?php $usuario->setNome($nome) ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile" disable>Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
           </div>

          </form>
```

Comment: Métodos `set()` geralmente não retornam valor. Se quer imprimir o valor no `value` do input não esqueça do `echo` ou `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro precisa acertar sua consulta, ou você named place holders que são aqueles tem dois pontos seguidos de um nome ex: `:id` ou place holders que são as interrogações.

Mude:

```
$sqlId = "SELECT * FROM web_cadcli WHERE idcad_cliente = ':id_us', nom_cliente = $this->getNome($nome), ema_cliente = $this->getEmail($email), senha_email = $this->senha($senha)  ";
```

Para:

```
$sqlId = "SELECT * FROM web_cadcli
 WHERE idcad_cliente = ?, nom_cliente = ?, ema_cliente = ?, senha_email = ?";
```

O segundo passo é arrumar os binds, cada interrogação deve ser 'arramada' com a sua posição na consulta. O primeiro valor sempre deve começar com um.

```
$sqlId->bindParam(1, $this->cod,   PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sqlId->bindParam(2, $this->nome,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlId->bindParam(3, $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sqlId->bindParam(4, $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Por último exibe o valor do objeto no formulario, troque o `set()` pelo `get()` e coloque um `echo` ou `print` antes. Lembre que o retorna da sua consulta é um array simples e não um objeto

mude:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="<?php $usuario->setNome($nome) ?>">
```

Para:

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value="<?php echo $usuario['nome']; ?>">
```